# Map an array inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I am trying to map an array inside of an array that I retrieve from firestore on the app initialization. Any ideas of what am I getting wrong? I am trying to map an inner array inside of the main array (the subarray I am trying to map is the "projects" array/object from below).

Screenshot of array that I am getting from Firestore can be found here:

[image]

I will post my code here:

```
<Container width="1080px">
      {response.map((array) => (
        <Container justifyContent="flex-start">
          <Organization>
            <Avatar src={avatar} />
            {array.organization}
          </Organization>

          {response.id.projects.map((project) => (
            <Project>
              <Thumbnail />
              <ProjectName>
                <ProjectYear>2020 &nbsp;•&nbsp; </ProjectYear>
                My Project Name
              </ProjectName>
            </Project>
          ))}
          ;
        </Container>
      ))}
      ;
    </Container>
```

This is how I fetch my data:

```
useEffect(() => {
firebase.db.collection('folders').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  const json = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data(),
  }));

  setResponse(json);
  console.log(json);
});
```

}, []);

Comment: Ciao, I was answering more or less like the other guys but now I see that you commented "cannot read property map of undefined". Could you add your response array like a text and not like an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're referring to is likely caused by your attempt to render empty array (having no nested arrays) upon initial render.

Try not setting initial value of `response` (i.e. `const [response, setResponse] = useState()`) and prepend JSX with the check whether your `response` already arrived before render.

And, of course, you need to use `.map()` properly:

```
return !!response.length && (<Container width="1080px">
      {response.map(({organization, projects, id}) => (
        <Container justifyContent="flex-start" key={id}>
          <Organization>
            <Avatar src={avatar} />
            {organization}
          </Organization>
          {!!projects.length && projects.map(({project_year, project_name}) => (
            <Project>
              <Thumbnail />
              <ProjectName>
                <ProjectYear>{project_year} &nbsp;•&nbsp; </ProjectYear>
                {project_name}
              </ProjectName>
            </Project>
          ))}
        </Container>
      ))}
</Container>
)
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined... This is the error I keep getting after every solution that is mentioned in this thread

Comment: @AdamSchwarcz : is this error triggered by the inner or outer map? If latter is the case, chances are that you may attempting to render your data *before* it actually arrives. Would you show wider code sample to see the part where you get data from firestore?

Comment: Hey I have added the useEffect in my main question

Comment: I think the problem is with the inner map

Comment: const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

Comment: This is what I did @charlietfl

Answer (score 2):

Ciao you could try something like:

```
{response && <Container width="1080px">
  {response.map((array) => (
    <Container justifyContent="flex-start">
      <Organization>
        <Avatar src={avatar} />
        {array.organization}
      </Organization>

      {array.projects.map((project) => (
        <Project>
          <Thumbnail />
          <ProjectName>
            <ProjectYear>2020 &nbsp;•&nbsp; </ProjectYear>
            My Project Name
          </ProjectName>
        </Project>
      ))}
      ;
    </Container>
  ))}
  ;
</Container> }
```

`response &&` is used to avoid to render data before getting it from firebase. `array.projects` because I saw on your picture that `projects` is not in `id`.

**EDIT**

I made a small example to show that map is working:

```js
let response = [{id: 1, organization: "org1", projects: [{project_year: "2020", project_name: "prj11"}, {project_year: "2020", project_name: "prj12"}]}, {id: 2, organization: "org2", projects: [{project_year: "2021", project_name: "prj21"}, {project_year: "2021", project_name: "prj21"}]}];

response.map((array) => {
   array.projects.map((project) => {
      console.log(project.project_year, project.project_name);
   })
})
```

I don't know, seems that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Still getting the same problem:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @AdamSchwarcz I update my answer with a small example to show that map funciotn write in this way is working. Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I see.. Sadly it doesnt help :( Still getting map of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the "array" variable.

```
<Container width="1080px">
  {response.map((array) => (
    <Container justifyContent="flex-start">
      <Organization>
        <Avatar src={avatar} />
        {array.organization}
      </Organization>

      {array.projects.map((project) => (
        <Project>
          <Thumbnail />
          <ProjectName>
            <ProjectYear>2020 &nbsp;•&nbsp; </ProjectYear>
            My Project Name
          </ProjectName>
        </Project>
      ))}
      ;
    </Container>
  ))}
  ;
</Container>
```